# Define a Custom Weekend Starting and Ending Day & Time and finding its occurrences over date range

Tags: c#, .net, date-range, weekend

I am having a tough time in calculating the number of custom defined weekends and later finding them over a specified date range, I have to apply different rates based on the days (weekends, season days & normal days).

For example, a trip is starting at 16/08/2017 09:00:00 and ending at 29/08/2017 09:00:00 where as my weekend start at Fri 15:00:00 till Mon 09:00:00 every week. I need to calculate how many weekends occur in the given trip start and end time and how many regular days, as both are charged at different rates. Any help is appreciated.

Please note that all the date and times will be dynamic and can be changed, so looking for a generic solution

Answer (score 0):

If your range is small enough you can try:

```
public class DateTimeRange
{
    private DateTime Start { get; set; }
    private DateTime End { get; set; }

    public DateTimeRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public int DayOffsCount()
    {
        var current = Start;
        var dayOffsCount = 0;
        while (current < End)
        {
            if (IsDayOff(current))
            {
                dayOffsCount++;
            }
            current = current.AddDays(1);
        }
        return dayOffsCount;
    }


}

 public bool IsDayOff(DateTime dt)
    {
        if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            return true;
        return IsHoliday(dt);
    }
```

Comment: trip days range may vary from days to months, but weekend days and time vary from site to site

Comment: plus we need to make this line dynamic also

if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)